# touchesMoved reaching out of my view bounds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, touchesmoved

I have subclassed UIView and there initially my view will be in a default color and i need to fill some different color on touch (from x axis = 0 to user touched point),here the problem is touchesMoved even if i drag out of my self view bounds it is getting those points,how to restrict it to only for my self view bounds.

I googled & tried below snippets but of no luck

```
if([self pointInside:point withEvent:nil]){
    [self fillColor];
}
```

My **touchesMoved** method is as below,

```
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
        endPoint = point;
        NSLog(@"moved x: %f,y: %f",point.x,point.y);
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([self frame], endPoint)){ // this also not working
            [self fillColor];
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your touchesMoved method,  `CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];`  replcae self by the view in which you wants the touch to be worked.

self will get the complete view, you should pass your drawingView at there, so that it will detetc touch only on that view.

Answer (score 0):

just set tag in `viewDidLoad:` method and use bellow logic..

```
fillColorView.tag = 111;
```

and use bellow logic in `touchesMoved:` method like bellow..

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{  
    UITouch *tap = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pointToMove = [tap locationInView:fillColorView];
     if([tap.view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) 
    {
        UIView *tempView=(UIView *) tap.view;
        if (tempView.tag == 111){
              [self fillColor];
        }
    }
}
```

hope this help you...

Comment: the thing is the above code snippet is in my view class(fillColorView) & i'm making this view as a [anyParentViewController addSubView:fillColorView] so when i use this when anyParentViewController is running if i move my finger in fillColorView even if i drag my finger out of bounds to my fillColorView it is filling color in my anyParentViewController.

Comment: CGPoint pointToMove = [tap locationInView:fillColorView]; also use my bellow code dude i also create this type of app for iPad in which use can draw line on view